# Shopify Functions Query Input

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

Im having trouble with my Shopify Function where I want to give a discount on the products if the client chooses pickup. Is there a way to get if the client picked PICK_UP as the delivery option ? I tried looking into this option [HERE](https://shopify.dev/api/functions/reference/shipping-discounts/graphql/common-objects/deliverymethod), but the response from shopify comes back empty does not matter if I choose shipping option or a pickup option. Here is my input query:

```
query Input {
  cart {
    lines {
      quantity
      merchandise {
        __typename
        ...on ProductVariant {
          id
        }
      }
    }
    deliveryGroups {
      selectedDeliveryOption {
        deliveryMethodType
      }
    }
  }
  discountNode {
    metafield(namespace: "this", key: "that") {
      value
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Any ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 1):

For those few of you who were looking into this. Apparently it IS a bug and the Shopify Devs are aware of it and are working to fix it. Until today it has not been fixed yet. Ill update here once the bug is fixed by shopify.